# Given $T_k=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \omega^{rk} z_r,~ \mbox{check if}~ S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} |T_k|^2=|\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} z_r |^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, summation

Here, $z_r$ are $n$-arbitrary complex numbers,  $\omega=e^{2i\pi/n}$ and $T_k=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \omega^{rk} z_r$, then  I prove that

$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n |T_k|^2= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \sum_{s=0}^{n-1} e^{2i\pi(r-s)k/n} z_r ~\bar z_s=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \sum_{s=0} ^{n-1} z_r ~\bar z_s \sum_{k=0}^n (e^{2i\pi (r-s)/n})^k$$
$$\Rightarrow S_n= \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \sum_{s=0}^{n-1} z_r ~\bar z_s   
\frac{e^{2i\pi (r-s)(n+1)/n}-1}{e^{2i\pi (r-s)/n}-1}= \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \sum_{s=0}^{n-1} z_r ~\bar z_s   
\frac{e^{2i\pi (r-s)/n}-1}{e^{2i\pi (r-s)/n}-1},~ \mbox{as}~ e^{2i\pi(r-s)}=1.$$
$$\Rightarrow S_n=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}z_r \sum_{s=0}^{n-1} \bar z_s = \left |\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} z_r  \right|^2.$$
Curiously, somehow the numerical experiments do not agree with this result. The question is what is amiss here? Please help.

Comment: when you are summing the geometric series, $r$ can be equal to $s$, in which case the term $\frac{1}{e^{2i\pi (r-s)/n}-1}$ is not defined.

Comment: @Anurag A, when $r=s$ that term becomes  $0/0$ but it's limit is 1.

Comment: But yours is a finite sum, you are not taking limits so those terms have to be dealt with separately.

Comment: @Anurag A, Thanks I will follow your suggestion, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Anurag A, now I get the correct result

Here, $z_r$ are $n$-arbitrary complex numbers,  $\omega=e^{2i\pi/n}$ and $T_k=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \omega^{rk} z_r$, then  I prove that

$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n |T_k|^2= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \sum_{s=0}^{n-1} e^{2i\pi(r-s)k/n} z_r ~\bar z_s=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \sum_{s=0} ^{n-1} z_r ~\bar z_s \left[\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (e^{2i\pi (r-s)/n})^k+1\right]$$

$$\Rightarrow S_n= \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \sum_{s=0}^{n-1} z_r ~\bar z_s \left [ 1+   
\frac{e^{2i\pi (r-s)}-1}{e^{2i\pi (r-s)/n}-1} \right]= \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \sum_{s=0}^{n-1} z_r ~\bar z_s  [1+n\delta_{r,s}]
~as~ e^{2i\pi(r-s)}=1. $$

$$\Rightarrow S_n=\left(\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} z_r \sum_{s=0}^{n-1} \ \bar z_s + n\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} z_r \bar z_r \right) = \left| \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} z_r \right|^2+ n \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} |z_r|^2.$$